# Removing the lowest numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

I'm trying to write a function that removes the lowest numbers then averages the remaining numbers in the list. Is there a way to remove the lowest two or more numbers from a list without using `sorted()` or `sort()`? Like using `min()` combined with `range()`.

What I have so far:

```
lst = [90, 100, 95, 95]
lst.remove(min(lst))
print(sum(lst) / len(lst))
```

Comment: Given that there is a tie for the second lowest number, what is the output you're even expecting?

Comment: Just an average of the numbers. Removing the 90 and averaging the remaining numbers gets me 97.5.

Comment: What should `lst` contain after removing 2 lowest numbers?

Comment: First one, then two, then all three, so 100 would the last one and also the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.remove` deletes *the first* matched value in the list. In order to remove all occurrences of the current lowest number, you'll have to call it `list.count(min(list))` times.

Here's the function that removes `n` smallest numbers from `lst` and that doesn't involve `list.remove`:

```
def remove_n_smallest(lst, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        m = min(lst)
        lst[:] = (x for x in lst if x != m)
```

And here's the example for `lst` from your question:

```
>>> remove_n_smallest(lst, 2)
>>> lst
[100]
>>> sum(lst) / len(lst)
100.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm having a bit of trouble getting that implemented. When I run the code it's not printing anything.

Comment: @DA_F: did you execute both the function definition _and_ the example below?

Answer (score 0):

I would just run it through a loop

```
>>> lst = [90,100,95,95]
>>> for i in range(0, 1):            # This removes n=1 items
...     lst.remove(min(lst))
... 
>>> lst
[100, 95, 95]
>>> lst = [90,100,95,95]
>>> for i in range(0, 2):           # This removes n=2 items
...     lst.remove(min(lst))
... 
>>> lst
[100, 95]
```

Comment: Because `list.remove` won't remove the second occurrence of 95.